# How to make an Asynchronous OkHttp call inAndroid using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am attempting to fetch API data with OkHttp using an inner class that inherits `AsyncTask<Request, Void, Response>`. Now when I try to initialize a response in the `doInBackground(vararg params: Request?): Response` method, I am forced to initialize the var `response : Response? = null` object like this, but I cannot set it to a nullable type, as the doInBackground() method expects a non-nullable `Response`. 
In Java, initializing `Response` was not mandatory. How do I circumvent this?

```
private class Fake : AsyncTask<Request, Void, Response>() {
        val client : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Request?): Response{
            // Initialization is compulsory, and cannot be set to Response() as it is not accessible
            var response : Response? = null 
        }

    }
```

Comment: If I don't use ```AsyncTask```, and make GET request in UI Thread as shown here, won't the app crash?

Comment: There are many ways of executing code in background. AsyncTask is deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, using Kotlin so in that case, you can use retrofit which works with HTTP client and for performing in background thread use coroutine.

It will perform API call in the background and update the Data on UI.

For more reference please learn coroutine

https://proandroiddev.com/using-retrofit-2-with-kotlin-coroutines-cb112f0fb738

Comment: That article is no longer available.

Comment: Hi, please checkout.and if you novices then it would be best for your learning.